# Add a class to a "fixed" img in stellar parallax

Tags: jquery, parallax, jquery-waypoints

I'm using the stellar parallax for a website

Demo: *http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html*

the files I'm using are from webtuts:
*http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/*

What I want to achieve, is to add a class to the "fixed" img at the center and changing it depending on the data-slide that is active.

I was able to change the image class when I click on a button of the menu but when I use the scroll bar to navigate, the class of the image doesn't change.

so I tried to add this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
  if ($('#quatre').hasClass('active')){     
    $('#circle').addClass('trans4');    
  }     
  else(){    
    $('#circle').removeClass('trans4');;     
  }});
});
```

as `#second` is the id of a slide and `#img-center` is the id of the image at the center of the page, but it didn't work

I also tried this code:

```
if(dataslide == 4){
    $('#circle').addClass('trans4');    
}
```

But that didn't work either

I'm totally a newb in javascript and I can't find a way to do this.

This is the HTML

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li id="un" data-slide="1"></li>
    <li id="deux" data-slide="2"></li>
    <li id="trois" data-slide="3"></li>
    <li id="quatre" data-slide="4"></li>
</ul>

<div id="circle"></div>

<div class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <!-- start content -->
    <div class="content clearfix">
        <div class="name">
            <h1>NOM</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="txt">
            <h2>some text</h2>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end content -->

    <a class="button" data-slide="2" title=""></a>
</div>

<div class="slide" id="slide2" data-slide="2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="txt">
            <h3>some text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="button" data-slide="3" title=""></a>
</div><!--End Slide 2-->

<div class="slide" id="slide3" data-slide="3" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="txt">
            <h3>some text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
<a class="button" data-slide="4" title=""></a>
</div><!--End Slide 3-->

<div class="slide" id="slide4" data-slide="4" data-stellar-background-ratio="0">
    <ul>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="1.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-55"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="1.25" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-53"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="2.7" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-150"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="3" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-100"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="1" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-75"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="2.2" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-55"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="1.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-53"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="2" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-15"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="1.3" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-150"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="1" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="1" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-55"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="1.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-53"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="2.7" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="3" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200"alt=""></li>
        <li class="rond" data-stellar-ratio="1" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200"alt=""></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="txt">
            <h3>some text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--End Slide 4-->
```

This is the js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    //initialise Stellar.js
    $(window).stellar();

    //Cache some variables
    var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
    slide = $('.slide');
    button = $('.button');
    mywindow = $(window);
    htmlbody = $('html,body');


    //Setup waypoints plugin
    slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

        //cache the variable of the data-slide attribute associated with each slide
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

        //If the user scrolls up change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and 
        //remove the active class from the previous navigation link 
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
        }
        // else If the user scrolls down change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and 
        //remove the active class from the next navigation link 
        else {
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
        }

    });

    //waypoints doesnt detect the first slide when user scrolls back up to the top so we add this little bit of code, that removes the class 
    //from navigation link slide 2 and adds it to navigation link slide 1. 
    mywindow.scroll(function () {
        if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    //Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
    //easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.
    function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
        htmlbody.animate({
            scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
        }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
    }



    //When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    links.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
    });

    //When the user clicks on the button, get the get the data-slide attribute value of the button and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    button.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);

    });

    if(dataslide == 4){
        $('#circle').addClass('trans4');    
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

This only fires once, when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
if ($('#quatre').hasClass('active')){     
$('#circle').addClass('trans4');    
}     
else(){    
$('#circle').removeClass('trans4');;     
}});
```

This will fire every time the window scrolls, which I believe is what you want:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {     
if ($('#quatre').hasClass('active')){     
$('#circle').addClass('trans4');    
}     
else(){    
$('#circle').removeClass('trans4');;     
}});
```